# How to close one activity to another

Tags: android

In my android app i have two activities, such as Activity a and Activity b. I want to close Activity a as well as Activity b from Activity a, I tried the code below, but an exception occurs,

```
a.this.Finish();//To finish current activity works fine
b.this.Finish();//Exception occurs because i tried to close from a Activity class.
```

So how to finish Activity b from Activity a? Guide me,

Comment: what is b and a instance of Activity class?

Comment: Why do you want to close an Activity from the other one? But if you want you can do this with broadcast (LocalBroadcastManager will be best). Proper BroadcastReceiver registration will assure, that you will close only opened Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start activity b for result and close it when activity a is closing:

Start of activity b:

```
Intent it = new Intent(a.this, b.class);
startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE); // REQUEST_CODE is int value
```

Finish of activity b:

```
finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity A to B

```
Intent b = new Intent(A.this,B.class);          
startActivity(b);
finish(); // Activity A will close it before starting B Activity.
```

Activity B to A

```
Intent a = new Intent(B.this,A.class);          
startActivity(a);
finish(); // Activity B will close it before starting A Activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

To `finish()` an `Activity`, you need to get this instance. But I think that if you want to control many `Activity`, I suggest you to use fragment. I meet your problem before and try to fix them but I meet more issue with that. So let try to use `Fragment`.